# How can i display "No records found" when there is no records in angular material tables

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I tried the below stackblitz link to display "No records found" message when there is no table data but the problem comes when I use data source of type **MatTableDataSource**.

stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8

Below is the code snippet am using:

```
this.serviceDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.services);
```

corresponding html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="serviceDataSource" matSort *ngIf="serviceDataSource.length > 0">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of serviceColumns" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{disCol}}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let rowValue">{{rowValue[disCol]}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="serviceColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rowdata; columns: serviceColumns;"></tr>
        </table>

        <div *ngIf="serviceDataSource.length === 0">No records found</div>
```

Below is the error am getting:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: there is no error in your demo, you can try ```*ngIf="!serviceDataSource.length```

Comment: Have added an answer, have a check!

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.serviceDataSource.data.length` instead of `this.serviceDataSource.length` to get the length of the dataSource.

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfphij)

In Material Design Page you can see the `MatTableDataSource` is using data object to manipulate the data.

[Material Data Source](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

its not for `serviceDataSource.length` its error because you dont Implementation in controller,
write :`serviceDataSource=[]`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with accessing of `serviceDataSource` before it was initialized. Better would be to have undefined check or simply modify the code as -

```
<div *ngIf="serviceDataSource?.length === 0">No records found</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="serviceDataSource && serviceDataSource.length === 0">No records found</div>
```

Comment: Tried with undefined check now..Error is gone but still there is no display message

Comment: `serviceDataSource.data.length` instead of `serviceDataSource.length` could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `?` after the variable name which `length` will be used here. `i.e: serviceDataSource?.length`

```
<div *ngIf="serviceDataSource?.length === 0">No records found</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below if your data coming from API:

```
*ngIf="serviceDataSource?.length == 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by checking variable itseft before going for `length` property like:

```
<span *ngIf="serviceDataSource">
   <div *ngIf="serviceDataSource.length === 0">No records found</div>
</span>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x44nvu) with `No record found` message

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best concept to display no record found in angular 2+.

```
<p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
</p>
<ng-container *ngIf="( items | filter : name) as result">
  <p *ngFor="let item of result">
    {{item.name}}
  </p>
  <p *ngIf="result.length === 0">No Result</p>  
</ng-container>
```